# jQuery UI Dialog - Keeping a clicked link inside an already open jQuery UI Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mardicion').each(function() {
        var $link = $(this);


        $link.click(function() {
            var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
                .load($link.attr('href') + ' #content')
                .dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    title: $link.attr('title'),
                    width: (pageWidth()*0.9),
                    height: (pageHeight()*0.9)
                });
                $dialog.dialog('open');

                return false;
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

I use the above javascript to load a page when I click a link, the page loads correctly but when I click another link inside the dialog the clicked link opens in the browser window instead of inside the dialog. I've heard that using a click handler is the proper way to do this (that the link opens inside the Dialog), but I'm not sure how to implement it with a  [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

Thanks!

Comment: can you add a bit of you html code please?

Comment: Sure here it is: <a id="mardicion" href='page3.html'>Open in Dialog</a>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have use the `live()` function. At a certain time (I guess on page load) you attach a click event handler to a certain number of items with the ID `mardicion`. When the page is loaded into your dialog, the links inside that page, even though they might have the `madicion` ID, their click events are not hooked up.

Use `$('#madicion').live('click' , function(e)  {})` to catch the click events also of all items, even if they are added to the page at a later stage.

As a side note:

1. it seems like you are misusing the ID attribute. You are only allowed to have one element per ID. Seeing `$('#XXX').each()` shows that you have more than 1 item. The correct way to handle these things is to give those elements a CSS class, and use `$('.XXX').each();`
2. The use of `each` is not necessary: `$('#XXX').click(function() { })` applies the stated function to each one of the elements.

Comment: Aren't I supposed to handle or use the live() function inside the page that I'm loading? In this case (See my comment in the question) 'page3.html'? Thanks!

Comment: No because you load the page as part of the existing page. So it is added to the existing page's DOM.